# Unable to define correct authorization rules... topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.Q1

Tags: activemq-classic

I am new to the ActiveMQ. I am trying to create two Queue Q1 and Q2, client1 and clients will write on the corresponding Qs. I am reading from the Queues as admin and it is running on the broker machine fine.

The issue is with producer side, they are reporting following error.

> JMSSecurityException: User client1 is not authorized to create: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.Q1

Following is the way I defining the simple authorization in activemq file. Please find the attachment full activemq.xml.
Could anyone help in resolving this issue.... Much appreciarted

```
<plugins>
        <!--  use JAAS to authenticate using the login.config file on the classpath to configure JAAS -->
        <!-- <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq" /> -->

        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="admin" password="${admin.password}"
                    groups="admins"/>
                <authenticationUser username="testuser1" password="${testuser1.password}"
                    groups="testusers1"/>
        <authenticationUser username="blbuser" password="${blbuser.password}" groups="client1"/>    
        <authenticationUser username="bpmuser" password="${bpmuser.password}" groups="client2"/>
        </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>

        <!--  lets configure a destination based authorization mechanism -->
        <authorizationPlugin>
            <map>
                <authorizationMap>
                    <authorizationEntries>
                        <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
                        <authorizationEntry queue="Q1" read="admins" write="client1" admin="admins" />
                        <authorizationEntry queue="Q2" read="admins" write="client2" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="admins,client1,client2" write="admins,client1,client2" admin="admins"/>   
                </authorizationEntries>            
                </authorizationMap>
            </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

You configuration grants admin right only to those in the admin group however that prevents the client connection from creating the advisory topics since creation of a destination is considered an admin function.  If you put the client groups into the admin role for the advisory bit then they should be able to create them, otherwise you will need to manually create all the needed advisory topics yourself before the clients start interacting with the broker.

Comment: So you recommend following changes.

Comment: <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="admins,client1,client2" write="admins,client1,client2" admin="admins,client1,client2"/>